# Display only upload field

Tags: python, django

I want to display only upload field on my project but need to save in my models(db): email address, file and date_time(this data was read from openpgp key)
It's works like: User uploads file(openpgp public key) on website and my script reads email and date_time from file.
I'm a newbie in django

Source code:

models.py:

```
class Users_Keys(models.Model):
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
file_key = models.FileField(max_length=255)
date_time = models.DateField()
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Users_Keys

class KeyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users_Keys
        fields = ('email', 'file_key', 'date_time')
```

view.py:

```
def upload_key(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = KeyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return  render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        form = KeyForm()
        

    return render(request, 'upload.html',{
    'form':form
})
```

upload.html:

```
{% extends 'background.html' %}

{% block content %}


<h2>Add KEY</h2>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Upload</button>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}  
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Read data from openPGP key:

```
def gpg_data():
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="/home/user/.gnupg")

    path = '/home/user/path_to_public.asc'

    import_result = gpg.scan_keys(path)
    key_info = dict(import_result[0])
    time_expire = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(key_info['expires']))
    email_address = str(key_info['uids']).split()[2].strip("<").replace(">","").replace("'","").replace(']',"")
```

Comment: Do you want to only display `file_key` field in the frontend or something else? It's not clear to me what you're asking. And why did you initialise `request.POST` 2 times in POST method of view?

Comment: Yes I want only display `file_key` in upload.html. I don't want show other field, but want to send data `email` and `date_time` to models. This data will be read from `file_key`

Comment: Do you mean in form of `upload.html`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think yeah. Creating webapp from me in this moment is black magic

Comment: I don't know the problem, but for displaying one field you can simply do `{{form.file_key}}` instead of {{form}}.

Comment: This is helpful and very easy if i know solution. Thank you. How i can send/modarate function `gpg_data` to send `time_expire` and `email_address` to other field?

Comment: Yes and can add details how to moderate function gpg_data to send information to others field?